# Giving color from Colors class as a parameter in Flutter

Tags: flutter

```
class colorSymbol extends StatelessWidget {
  final Colors color;
  
  colorSymbol(Colors this.color,  {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Icon(
      Icons.accessibility,
      color: ,
      size: 64.0,
    );
  }
}
```

The code simply return a accessibility icon from Icons and I want this widget to change its color which is given by user. I created a variable from Colors class called color but I cannot move on. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You like to have [`Color`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color-class.html) instead of [`Colors`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/vector_math_64/Colors-class.html).

```dart
class colorSymbol extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color color;
  const colorSymbol(this.color, {super.key}) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your parameter type from `Colors` to `Color` :

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class colorSymbol extends StatelessWidget {
      final Color color;
      
      colorSymbol(Color this.color,  {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Icon(
          Icons.accessibility,
          color: color,
          size: 64.0,
        );
      }
    }
```